# How to pass an array to the Google Maps destination matrix api, destinations parameter in jquery?

Tags: jquery, arrays, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I had a look at different answers here but seems that there is not much about it.
I have this array, filled with destination points:

[image: Picture is from the google chrome console.]

And I have the following code where I make a call to the Google maps destinations matrix api :

```
 var distanceService = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
            distanceService.getDistanceMatrix({
                    origins: [pos],
                    destinations: [points],
                    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
                    unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC,
                    durationInTraffic: true,
                    avoidHighways: false,
                    avoidTolls: false
                },
                function (response, status) {
                    if (status !== google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK) {
                        console.log('Error:', status);
                    } else {
                        console.log(response);
                    }
                });
```

The code works fine if I pass just one array object to the `destinations` parameter, like:

```
destinations:[points[1]]
```

or if I give multiple destinations like:

```
destinations:[points[0],points[1],points[2]],
```

But if I pass the whole array to the `destinations` parameter like you see in the main code picture, I get the following error:

> ```
> InvalidValueError: in property destinations: at index 0: not a string; and not a LatLng or LatLngLiteral: in property lat: not a
> ```
>
> number; and unknown property 0

Google maps API says that you can pass an array to the `destinations` parameter but what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: try `destinations: [points.map(function(point){return point;})]`

Comment: @ElmerDantas thanks but doesn't work

Comment: As I've never used this API, I'm just guessing what you can do...for example, if accepts `Array` and `points` is already an Array, maybe you don't need the brackets..it will be just `destinations: points`

Comment: @ElmerDantas Your last answer was right. I passed the Array without the [] and it worked.

Comment: that's great! I put as answer as well ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if accepts Array and points is already an Array, maybe you don't need the brackets..it will be just `destinations: points`